# Facebook Sign Up Link Broken

Tags: facebook

I've set up a Facebook Like button on my site. It seems to work fine. If I like something it appears on my Timeline and all the links work.

However, if I'm **logged out** of Facebook and you get the message 'Sign up to see what your friends like'. Clicking **sign up** takes you to Facebook and tries redirecting to r.php.

The Javascript code I have in my footer is exactly what Facebook suggests:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=487139091399600";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Sample page is

http://www.visitkievukraine.com/accommodation/premier-palace/

Run through the debugger fine.

Comment: sorry, it's not really clear what you are asking here

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Make sure you are logged out of Facebook. You'll see a message next to the Like button asking you to Sign Up to Facebook. Click it and it will redirect you to a broken page. If you are logged in and you click the like button everything seems ok. Test it here http://www.visitkievukraine.com/accommodation/premier-palace/ Hope you can help.